# how to write XML code about a relativelayout , in java language

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to write this piece XML code about a relativelayout , in java language.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/xK1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
android:visibility="gone">
<include android:id="@+id/xKeyBoard" layout="@layout/keyboard"></include>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to get this to work programmatically in your code. The LayoutInflator is doing what the include tag does in the XML. Hope this helps!

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
rl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
rl.setId(someId);
rl.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
rl.setOrientation(RelativeLayout.VERTICAL);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
   this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    
rl.addView(0, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.keyboard, this, false));
```